# is there a webpage or api showing all Cocoapods packages?

Tags: cocoapods

I try to get a list of all Cocoapods packages. And I cannot find a webpage with this information.
Is there something for Cocoapods similar to pypi.org/simple for python?
or replicate.npmjs.com/_all_docs for npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs - the master repo for all podspecs.